# Share Java Canvas Between Processes

Tags: java, java-native-interface, awt, java-canvas

How can I create a `java.awt.Canvas` object in a Java process and pass it to another (child) process, and let the other process put lightweight (swing) components on it. The child process should handle the events of the components that it put onto the canvas. And of course event dispatching thread(s) should function as expected.

Comment: share between Processes or threads?

Comment: processes. threads, I can handle :)

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible to share a `Canvas` between two processes because a Canvas is an object instance and you can share informations about the object, not the object instance.

For example you can eventually duplicate the Canvas on the two processes, but changing a value on one process will not be reflected on the second process because memory is isolated between processes.

---

What is possible to do is to create a class that operate on the canvas from one process and that can accept instructions from outside using a Socket as a communication system. So in this case you have one Canvas "director" and many processes that can interact with it.

Comment: I was thinking about some native approaches, possibly with JNA.

Comment: Technically should be possible to share memory between processes (at least in linux) but is really complicate (not sure if possible) to access information related to a JVM. The better solution should be to use a single point access to modify the canvas that expose methods to be called from outside using a socket mechanism